# Pages are not displaying on the front end properly

Tags: magento2, frontend, cache

I don't know what my developers did but a site that was loading fine is now showing users basically I'm assuming how a bot sees it. Only shows menus at the text, no pictures unless you scroll so far down the page after the menu trees. See screenshot. I'm not a developer but need to know how to fix this as my developer can't recreate the error but I get customers calling and using Lucky Orange to watch customers on-site, this is what I see. Every single person coming to the site is leaving immediately so I know there is an issue (and more importantly, no orders).  I tried clearing the cache on Magento. My server company cleared the cache. I cleared the cache on CDN (sucuri).  It is also, in this screenshot is showing my trust symbol on the bottom right with 2/18 date but this was a visitor that visited the site today (3/5).  I wonder if this means they are looking at an older version of the site for some reason?

What may cause this?

Any help as my developer is not being helpful with this continuous issue. It doesn't happen for everyone which is part of the problem. But 90% of the visitors today did get this error.

[image]

Comment: Your site is in Magento2?

Comment: just share url please

Answer (score 0):

First the backup the you pub/static folder

Run the this commands

```
rm -rf var/cache
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento i:rei
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento c:f
```

And Second Check :-

First of all, apply proper permissions, enable apache rewrite_module and refresh apache server.

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/MAGENTO_2_ROOT_DIRECTORY/

sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo service apache2 restart
```

For messy frontend, run following command from Magento root:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Now clear var directory except .htaccess file and check admin. If you get 404 page, there may be an issue of Symlink. Fot this, Edit apache config file

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and replace this code :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride none
Require all granted
```

with

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

Note: changed `AllowOverride` none to `AllowOverride` All

Now restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` and check admin. This should fix admin 404 issue.

Also make sure, you don't leave /app/etc/ directory writeable

Answer (score 0):

please check if the console is returning 404 on your console. If so, then run the deploy correctly for the deploy in the corresponding language. For example:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>] [-t|--theme[="<theme>"]] [--exclude-theme[="<theme>"]] [-l|--language[="<language>"]] [--exclude-language[="<language>"]] [-a|--area[="<area>"]] [--exclude-area[="<area>"]] [-j|--jobs[="<number>"]]  [--no-javascript] [--no-css] [--no-less] [--no-images] [--no-fonts] [--no-html] [--no-misc] [--no-html-minify] [-f|--force]
```